# Download a file without reducing the file size in android

Tags: android, kotlin, download, android-download-manager

In my application users upload an encrypted file (`.crypt`) file to their google drive and provide an shareable link.

What I want to do is to download the file and decrypt it. But the problem is when i am downloading the file **file-size is reduced** from a certain amount (have no idea; may be it is compressed automatically when downloading or any other fault i am doing).

because of that I cant decrypt the file using the key.

I tried following methods for downloading the file.

METHOD 1

```
fun download(link: String, path: String) {
    URL(link).openStream().use { input ->
        FileOutputStream(File(path)).use { output ->
            input.copyTo(output)
        }
    }
}
```

METHOD 2

```
val downloadmanager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pfaZSJDtex763-8vyTF-Z8uAl4dqAwMZ/view?usp=sharing")

val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
request.setTitle("new1")
request.setDescription("Downloading")         

request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/new1.crypt/"))
downloadmanager.enqueue(request)
```

Method Using to Encrypt the Image file

```
  fun encryptFile(inputStream: InputStream, path: String): Boolean {
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Eee.crypt/"
        )
        var key: ByteArray = ("123456789").toByteArray(charset("UTF-8"))
        val messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
        key = messageDigest.digest(key)
        key = key.copyOf(16)
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec)
        val cipherOutputStream = CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, cipher)
        var b: Int
        val d = ByteArray(8)
        while (inputStream.read(d).also { b = it } != -1) {
            cipherOutputStream.write(d, 0, b)
        }
        cipherOutputStream.flush()
        cipherOutputStream.close()
        inputStream.close()
        val encryptedFile = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Eee.crypt/"
        )
        return encryptedFile.exists()
    }
```

Example encrypted file I want to download is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pfaZSJDtex763-8vyTF-Z8uAl4dqAwMZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There's a decent chance it's been compressed with gzip, but gzip is lossless and decoded at the end of the tunnel. You shouldn't lose enough bytes to be unable to decrypt it

Comment: @Zoe original file is 3MB and after downloading it is 70KB

Comment: You can not download files from google drive this way. The link that you have is only a link to a web page (you are downloading a web page). In other words you can not download files from google drive programmatically using the link this way. Search to find if there is any API for downloading files from google drive.